# Clearing Firefox Update History

Tags: firefox, firefox-profile

Is there a way to clear the Firefox update history seen in *about:preferences > General > Firefox Updates > Show Update History*?

Even after looking through my whole profile folder and using grep to locate the history, I just can't seem to find it and my OCD would *really* like to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Firefox update history is not stored as part of the profile. Instead, it is located in “All Users AppData”, `C:\ProgramData\Mozilla-SOME-GUID\updates`. There is a folder per Firefox instance, it contains a file `update.xml`. It looks like this (for Firefox Developer Edition):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<updates xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/2005/app-update">
  <update appVersion="109.0" buildID="20230105190654" channel="aurora" detailsURL="https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/109.0/releasenotes/" displayVersion="109.0 Beta 9" installDate="1673250946407" isCompleteUpdate="false" name="Firefox Developer Edition 109.0 Beta 9" previousAppVersion="109.0" promptWaitTime="691200" serviceURL="https://aus5.mozilla.org/update/6/Firefox/109.0/20221222190305/WINNT_x86_64-msvc-x64/en-US/aurora/Windows_NT%2010.0.0.0.19045.2364%20(x64)/ISET:SSE4_2,MEM:32488/default/default/update.xml" type="minor" statusText="The Update was successfully installed">
    <patch size="62209899" type="complete" URL="https://download.mozilla.org/?product=devedition-109.0b9-complete&os=win64&lang=en-US" hashFunction="sha512" hashValue="5afec9a644b156d615030e22ff758cdc8d5f47aa1de276697c832e4478bd461d99b25cdc03bb016abafd472ae89141a25069d9cc30837b953af0b3bb4d80bfd9"/>
    <patch size="15792336" type="partial" URL="https://download.mozilla.org/?product=devedition-109.0b9-partial-109.0b6&os=win64&lang=en-US" finalURL="https://download-installer.cdn.mozilla.net/pub/devedition/releases/109.0b9/update/win64/en-US/firefox-109.0b6-109.0b9.partial.mar" selected="true" state="succeeded" hashFunction="sha512" hashValue="b89f1296a9bef623ed8097711c8b62ed2a6db8aae0618cdac3e701d5be2afbe3ca3af190c444f08952195f23f16602d7d580429c068f867b87851c470bccfba0" internalResult="0"/>
  </update>
  <update appVersion="109.0" buildID="20221222190305" channel="aurora" detailsURL="https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/109.0/releasenotes/" displayVersion="109.0 Beta 6" installDate="1671785847658" isCompleteUpdate="false" name="Firefox Developer Edition 109.0 Beta 6" previousAppVersion="109.0" promptWaitTime="691200" serviceURL="https://aus5.mozilla.org/update/6/Firefox/109.0/20221220185745/WINNT_x86_64-msvc-x64/en-US/aurora/Windows_NT%2010.0.0.0.19045.2364%20(x64)/ISET:SSE4_2,MEM:32488/default/default/update.xml" type="minor" statusText="The Update was successfully installed">
    <patch size="62739779" type="complete" URL="https://download.mozilla.org/?product=devedition-109.0b6-complete&os=win64&lang=en-US" hashFunction="sha512" hashValue="ed8b57cb784316e38e2339f117c56b6e12cc145cfe3332b50613e211654908d54af7780c422f19c235f02dd2023c23fa6e5dd279f84b19d3608ef9cf6c1456c7"/>
    <patch size="8284839" type="partial" URL="https://download.mozilla.org/?product=devedition-109.0b6-partial-109.0b5&os=win64&lang=en-US" finalURL="https://download-installer.cdn.mozilla.net/pub/devedition/releases/109.0b6/update/win64/en-US/firefox-109.0b5-109.0b6.partial.mar" selected="true" state="succeeded" hashFunction="sha512" hashValue="21932a42e1ce04ef0e387f482120532886da4a9f5269bf4ecbb72fc2c88afcc5eb86e608a2686516af76ab0946376bff737a063667139c597257457d381d497d" internalResult="0"/>
  </update>
  <!-- ... -->
</updates>
```

It’s probably safe to modify or delete this file.

Things may be different if you do not have the Mozilla Maintenance Service installed.

Comment: Thank you so much! Deleting this file completely cleared the update history.

In case it might help someone else, here's the file location on macOS:
`/Users/Carapuce/Library/Caches/Mozilla/updates/Applications/Firefox/updates.xml`